# spectrum of a general algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, definition, algebras

For unital Algebras $A$, the Spectrum of an element $x \in A$ is defined to be
$$
Sp_A(x) := \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C}: x - \lambda * e  \text{ is not invertible} \}
$$
According to my textbook, there is a way we can extend this definition to non-unital Algebras: Let $A$ be an algebra, then define $A_I := A \times \mathbb{C}$ with the operation: $(x,\lambda) · (y, \mu) = (xy + \lambda + \mu, \lambda \mu)$. Then, $A_I$ is a unital Algebra with unit $e:= (0,1)$ and we define
$$
Sp_A(x) = Sp_{A_I}(x)
$$
My problem is, that $x$  as an element of $A$ is not a well defined element of $A_I$; how should I understand this? Any help is apreciated

Comment: Should be $\text{Sp}_A(x):=\text{Sp}_{A_I}((x,0))$.

Comment: Usually, $A$ is considered a subalgebra of $A_I$ via the embedding $A \ni x \mapsto (x, 0) \in A_I$.